# Should I use "to" or not?

Tags: grammar

> I can give **to** Sophie a lot more than what she expects.

or

> I can give Sophie a lot more than what she expects.

Which one is grammatical?

Comment: Both constructions would be neater minus the redundant **what**.

Answer (score 2):

Both are grammatically correct, however **to Sophie** sounds a little formal/stuffy. Though English speakers love extra prepositonal phrases, certain uses can make the sentence sound a little wordy. Having Sophie as the indirect object rather than the object of preposition sounds  better in this situation. I'd suggest going with the one that does **not have have the to** in it for most situations.